# How to increase or decrease a value by taking data from the input field using use State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field. I have to take the data and set the data by adding the previous value. I want to try it with the useState function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`const [data, setData] = useState(0)` // it is initial value and first assignment

`setData((lastValue) => lastValue+1)` // and Here lastValue is 0 and by increase it change to 1, Once again and again Whenever you call setter of State